PostgreSQL does not change the column type from text to jsonb
I have one database prefilled (from one migration tool) with data. Inside I have a table that has three columns, that in the previous database were text columns containing json strings. The migration tool extracted them as columns of type TEXT, but now I want to convert them in jsonb column type.
I tried with a simple ALTER command:
ALTER TABLE public.reporting_field ALTER COLUMN field_value_after_automation TYPE jsonb USING field_value_after_automation::jsonb;

The result (I'm using PG Admin to send commands) is:
ALTER TABLE

Query returned successfully in 31 msec.

And when I inspect the table with:
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'reporting_field' AND column_name = 'field_value_after_automation';

the result is:

I presumed that there is some conversion errors that are not shown in the ALTER statement, so I run this command to ensure that there is no broken data in this column:
SELECT field_value_after_automation
FROM public.reporting_field
WHERE field_value_after_automation NOT NULL
  AND field_value_after_automation::jsonb IS NULL;

And it returned empty result set.
I'm puzzled, why the conversion is not done, since everything looks fine?
Regards,
Yulian

UPDATE
As suggested @David R I used
ALTER TABLE public.reporting_field ALTER COLUMN field_value_after_automation SET DATA TYPE jsonb USING field_value_after_automation::jsonb;

And because I have three columns that I have to convert, for the first one it converted it. But for the second end third - no.
Why is this strange behavior?

Shouldn't the command be => ALTER TABLE public.reporting_field ALTER COLUMN field_value_after_automation SET DATA TYPE jsonb USING field_value_after_automation::jsonb; ? (i.e TYPE should be SET DATA TYPE I presume)

@DavidR It's optional, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html. Both TYPE and SET DATA TYPE are doing the same.

The strange thing is that @DavidR suggestion converted the column to jsonb ....

But I have three columns, First one went well but the other two, they are not converted............

@YulianDimitrov Strange!!

disconnected the server connection, connected again and it converted it......

My guess is you kept your transaction open and verified the result from another session. Depending on the client type and config, autocommit could've acted weird depending on where your cursor/caret was positioned, if/what was selected and whether you ran the code using one button, another button, or one of multiple keyboard shortcuts. There's zero difference between the two syntactic variants of alter column - they both do the exact same thing, the exact same way so there's no way that's what lead to the change being applied "partially".

If you want to figure out what really happened, retrace your steps taking note exactly which statement you're running from which client/window/tab, what's selected and where your cursor or selection is, how you launch it (buttons, shortcuts), what's the current autocommit setting in a given context, and whether you maybe opened a transaction explicitly (leading begin; earlier in your script). Paste the code you're really running, not just something vaguely resembling it. If you're not allowed to share it, make a mock test that lets you reproduce the problem and share that instead.
